# Turn subquery into join query

Tags: mysql, sql

For this query:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` FROM users WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT user_one, user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one='$my_id' OR user_two = '$my_id')
```

I get this error message:

> Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Would it be possible to use 2 columns in a join instead of a subquery? And if yes, how?

Comment: Sure, but in the query you are doing you do not need the second select column to use them in your where clause. Unless you need user_two, in which case, you can use a UNION in your subquery. One select for user_one, unioned to a second select for user_two.

Comment: But I would like to just display one of the two columns, depending on which one is not me. It is possible that either user_one or user_two is myself, depending on who asked who to be friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a union like this:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` 
        FROM users 
           WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT user_one FROM friends 
                                               where user_one = '$my_id'
                               UNION
                               SELECT user_two FROM friends 
                                               where user_two = '$my_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want records from the `users` table where your user_id is in user_one or user_two of the `friends` table, you can do the following:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` 
FROM users 
WHERE `user_id` IN (
    SELECT user_one 
    FROM friends 
    WHERE user_one = '$my_id'
)
UNION ALL
SELECT `user_id`, `user_name` 
FROM users 
WHERE `user_id` IN (
    SELECT user_two 
    FROM friends 
    WHERE user_two = '$my_id'
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! For some reason I get my name not my friend's name.

Comment: That's because there WHERE clause needs to be the opposite of what's in the SELECT clause for each part of the union. @kringeltorte

Answer (score 0):

select a.userid,a.username
from users a
inner join friends b
on a.userid=b.userid
where b.user_one='$my_id' or b.user_two='$my_id'

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users U
join friends F
ON F.user_id=U.user_id
and F.user_name=U.user_name
WHERE  F.user_one='$my_id' OR F.user_two = '$my_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the error because an IN clause cannot select on more than one column in a where statement.

I think what you are looking for may be something like this

```
SELECT 
    user_id, 
    user_name 
FROM users INNER JOIN Friends ON Users.User_ID = User_one OR Users.User_ID = User_Two
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user_id, user_name
FROM users a, friends b
WHERE a.user_id = b.user_one 
AND (b.user_one='$my_id' OR b.user_two = '$my_id')

Answer (score 0):

The IN operand only takes one parameter. If you want to get all of the people you are friends with, you need to do so in a way that only returns one column. You can do something like that with a UNION:

```
SELECT user_one
FROM friends
WHERE user_two = 'me'
UNION
SELECT user_two
FROM friends
WHERE user_one = 'me';
```

Then, use that as your IN parameter:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name
FROM users
WHERE user_id IN(
   SELECT user_one
   FROM friends
   WHERE user_two = 'me'
   UNION
   SELECT user_two
   FROM friends
   WHERE user_one = 'me');
```